# why isn't this Jquery readingthe correct radio button checked value?

Tags: jquery, radio-button

i have the following code in an asp.net-mvc view:

```
<input checked="checked" id="outputFilter" name="outputFilter" value="Detail" type="radio"> Detail Info
<input id="outputFilter" name="outputFilter" value="Summary" type="radio"> Summary Info

<input checked="checked" id="outputSorting" name="outputSorting" value="Milestone" type="radio"> Milestone
<input id="outputSorting" name="outputSorting" value="AppRank" type="radio">App --&gt; Rank
```

and i have this javascript code:

```
 var sortValue = $("input[@name='outputSorting']:checked").val();
 var dataValue = $("input[@name='outputFilter']:checked").val();
```

the issue is that i get the value "Detail" for BOTH sortValue and dataValue

can anyone see anything wrong with this code that would lead this to be the case??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `@` sign. That has been deprecated long ago for attributes.

```
var sortValue = $("input[name='outputSorting']:checked").val();
var dataValue = $("input[name='outputFilter']:checked").val();
```

Also, close your input tags to make the HTML valid.

```
<input ... value="Detail" type="radio" /> Detail Info
<input id="outputFilter" ... type="radio" /> Summary Info
...
```

- [Your code](http://jsfiddle.net/anurag/R9nbT/) with jQuery 1.2.6 (works).
- [Your code](http://jsfiddle.net/anurag/R9nbT/1/) with jQuery 1.3.2 (doesn't work).

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the '@' symbol. Hope this helps.

Bob

Answer (score -1):

Also, IDs have to be unique. Use classes instead